# A function that takes a pattern of skips that will take an array and return the new arr

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create some sort of pattern of skips that I will set onto an array with the ability to choose which item of the array will be the first item of this "pattern" of skips and then return the items chosen by the pattern.

For example, I need to jump `2 2 1 2` in this `arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` so if its the second item (2) it will return `[2,4,6,7,9]` does anybody knows a way in JS to do this??

Comment: can you provide more example ?

Comment: what did you tried so far, can you show us your code? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are usually zero-indexed so saying the start index is two corresponds to the second element in the array is a bit odd, but something like this should get you started.

```
function skip (start, pattern, arr)
{
    let idx = 0,
    res = [ ];

    pattern.unshift (start == 0 ? start : start - 1); // A bit odd but to accomodate the 1st index in the array being called the second element. You can just make this pattern.unshift (start); if you want to do it normally :)

    for (let i of pattern) {
        idx += i;
        res.push (arr [idx]);
    }

    return res;
}
```

will give:

```
=> skip (2, [ 2, 2, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]);
[ 2, 4, 6, 7, 9 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
var original = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var pattern = [2,2,1,2];

console.log(cutArray(original, pattern));

function cutArray(originalArray, jumpPatternArray){
    for(var i = 0; jumpPatternArray.length > i; i++)
        originalArray.splice(i, jumpPatternArray[i] - 1);    
    return originalArray;
}
```